# Need to check the string ends with a particular extension or not in Perl script

Tags: perl

```
input1 = "charles.ma@abc.com"
input2 = "charles.ma"
```

Need to print the value if it ends with only `.ma` so only `input2` should print.

The function should pass `input1` as it is not ending with `.ma` followed by `@abc`.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us the [mcve] you already have. This helps us to address your problem more closely

Answer (score 7):

You can use a regex:

```
print $string if $string =~ /\.ma\z/;
```

Or use [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr):

```
print $string if '.ma' eq substr $string, -length('.ma');
```

or use [rindex](http://p3rl.org/rindex)

```
my $r = rindex $string, '.ma';
print $string if -1 != $r && length($string) == length('.ma') + $r;
```

Comment: The rindex solution is flawed:

If checking "hello" ends with "whoops", or any other 6 letter string, it will evaluate to true.  That's because rindex will return -1 to indicate not found.  And length("hello") does equal length("whoops") -1

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what your data actually is. Does it end in '.ma' or '.ma"'? In my code below, I've assumed the latter.

This is a pretty simple use of regular expressions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  print if /\.ma"$/;
}

__DATA__
input1 = "charles.ma@abc.com"
input2 = "charles.ma"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function :

```
sub end_by($){
    my $string = shift;
    if ($string =~ m/\.ma$/) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And so call it like that :

```
print $input1 if end_by($input1);
print $input2 if end_by($input2);
```

Comment: Perl programmers tend to prefer snake_case over camelCase, so the function would be called `end_by()` (or, probably better, `ends_in()`) :-)

Comment: Should be `.ma\z` instead of `.ma$` unless you want to allow `"foo.ma\n"` to pass.

Comment: That `.*` will just slow things down (potentially by a lot). Get rid of it

Comment: All you need: `return $string =~ /\.ma\z/;`

Comment: Your prototype claims `end_by` takes no arguments. If you do it like that, `end_by($input1)` won't even compile.